# dijit.Editor doesn't display Japanese characters

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using the Dojo Toolkit to build an SRS to both aid in my learning of both the Dojo Toolkit and the Japanese language.

For those of your who don't know an SRS is basically a flash card system.

So, I have a side bar where I can choose a deck of cards to review and when I click on a deck from the list it opens up a new tab in a `TabContainer` which contains two `ContentPane`s.

One `ContentPane` contains a `DataGrid` which currently uses an `ItemFileWriteStore` with a `url` to a `json` file.

The `json` file contains the items for the `DataGrid` with each item possesing an `id`, `question` and `answer`.

The `id` is currently just an `integer` value and the `question` and `answer` both contain Japanese strings.

The idea is that when a row in the `DataGrid` is clicked, the `ContentPane` below the one containing the `DataGrid` should have it's contents replaced with a `dijit.Editor`.

The original contents of the `ContentPane` before they are replaced is just a simple string saying `Click on the rows in the grid above to edit a card's details`.

I am creating the `dijit.Editor` programmatically and everything works well until I try to give it a Japanese string from the `DataGrid`'s row.

This is my JavaScript which gets the `DataGrid` row's information and creates the `dijit.Editor`:

(`grid` is the `DataGrid` object and `card_details` is the `id` of the `ContentPane`)

```
dojo.connect(grid, 'onRowClick', function(e) {
    var id = grid.getItem(e.rowIndex).id;
    var question = grid.getItem(e.rowIndex).question;
    var answer = grid.getItem(e.rowIndex).answer;

    dojo.byId('card_details').innerHTML = '';

    var editor = new dijit.Editor({
        id: 'editor',
        value: question
    }, dojo.byId('card_details'));
});
```

The code above creates the `dijit.Editor` in the `ContentPane` but doesn't fill it with the value stored in the `question` variable (I have logged and alerted the variable and it does contain the expected value).

However if I replace the variable with a literal string like `My String` or even something in Japanese like `反乱者` it works just fine.

It even works if I replace: `var question = grid.getItem(e.rowIndex).question;` with: `var question = '反乱者';`

Does anybody know why it won't work when using the `question` variable when it has been assigned it's value via `grid.getItem(e.rowIndex).question`?

I am still a beginner when it comes to Dojo Toolkit so I'm sure it must be something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question now.

It turns out I just needed to change:

```
var question = grid.getItem(e.rowIndex).question;
```

to:

```
var question = grid.store.getValue(grid.getItem(e.rowIndex), 'question');
```